Kamal Setup Error: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
I am setting up rails 7 + postgres application deployment on an EC2 ubuntu instance using kamal 2. All the containers are building and starting up fine except for the rails app container which is unable to be fired up. I am getting this error when running kamal setup:
INFO [b770f8ed] Finished in 0.867 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [afea50ed] Running docker exec kamal-proxy kamal-proxy deploy doordepot-web --target="e574c13c02ae:3000" --deploy-timeout="30s" --drain-timeout="30s" --buffer-requests --buffer-responses --log-request-header="Cache-Control" --log-request-header="Last-Modified" --log-request-header="User-Agent" on x.x.x.x
 ERROR Failed to boot web on x.x.x.x
  INFO First web container is unhealthy on x.x.x.x, not booting any other roles
  INFO [b8782eb5] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^doordepot-web-7b4a17845abcd627c29b810dbf2386476e85903f$ --quiet | xargs docker logs --timestamps 2>&1 on x.x.x.x
  INFO [b8782eb5] Finished in 1.235 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 ERROR 2024-11-25T18:03:34.760918670Z bin/rails aborted!
2024-11-25T18:03:34.773757665Z ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
2024-11-25T18:03:34.773917647Z /rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2024-11-25T18:03:34.773964950Z Tasks: TOP => db:prepare => db:load_config => environment
2024-11-25T18:03:34.773995507Z (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2024-11-25T18:03:36.438143169Z bin/rails aborted! 

This is what I see when I run docker ps -a on server:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS                                                                      NAMES
e574c13c02ae   usrname/app:7b4a17845abcd627c29b810dbf2386476e85903f   "/rails/bin/docker-e…"   9 minutes ago    Exited (1) 9 minutes ago                                                                              doordepot-web-7b4a17845abcd627c29b810dbf2386476e85903f
efd6d57f5dea   basecamp/kamal-proxy:v0.8.2                                  "kamal-proxy run"        9 minutes ago    Up 9 minutes               0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   kamal-proxy
9895da41d87a   postgres:17                                                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes              127.0.0.1:5432->5432/tcp                                                   doordepot-db

I feel like the env secrets from .kamal/secrets are not being correctly applied to the database.yml which looks like this:
production:
  <<: *default
  database: doordepot_production
  username: doordepot
  password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>
  host: <%= ENV["DB_HOST"] %>


@engineersmnky I did create new creds and master key but the error persists.

Have you seen this: https://github.com/basecamp/kamal/issues/985

https://kamal.wiki/setup/how-to-setup-kamal/
Check this and use RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(cat config/credentials/production.key) if you are using environment specific keys
